# lxml for a large text file, stops before the end of file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using lxml to parse through a large xml file (~2GB) which contains articles and authors that have published them (like so):

```
<article>
 <author>Name 1</author>
 <author>Name 2</author>
 <title> title </title>
 <year> 777 </year>
 <ref> some ref </ref>
 <citi>/here/there<citi>
</article>
```

What I need to do is fetch the names of authors that contain certain word in the 'citi' tag and keep count of how many times the tag occurs.
(Bascially count the number of authors that have done some work related to a keyword (and also keep a count of how many times the author has worked with that keyword))

There were two problems:
1. My xml file contains some external entities like (`<author> Name &Oun </author>`), and I wanted them to be ignored. I read online that by default lxml doesnt resolve those identites, however it does parse all entries and I just catch the exception if it is thrown.
2. However, it doesn't parse the entire file and stops at a certain point after throwing the exception.

I think it is because before reading the next chunk, the exception is being thrown and I am not sure on how to avoid this.

My current working code is this:
(It's just a makeshift code, so I realise there could be better ways of doing some steps, but if you feel it can be improved let me know)

```
authors=Counter()
cache_authors=[]

def parseXMLDOC():
    flag=True
    try:
        for event, elem in etree.iterparse(self.file):
        # Keep the current authors in a cache
       if elem.tag == "author":
           cache_authors.append(elem.text)

        # check for keyword
       if elem.tag=="cite" and flag:
             # checks if the keyword exists and if it does, it adds
             # it to authors Counter above
           flag=not self.checkCitations(elem.text)

       # clean up for parsing the next article
       if elem.tag == "article":
           cache_article=[]
           flag=True
       # print event,elem.tag,elem.text
           elem.clear();
     except etree.XMLSyntaxError:
           print("Unidentified entities encountered")
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with such large XML files, the old-fashioned SAX approach is preferable to DOM. Basically, you don't want to keep a huge parsed tree of the document in RAM and navigate it. Rather, you react to individual events like opening and closing tags. For example, see [the pyexpat module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html#example) . This approach is more efficient, but more tedious: you have to implement a (small) state machine.